# PHPMaker 2019 | Join in "Recordset_Selecting?

Tags: php, sql, oracle

There are two tables. The data from Table A must be filtered. But I can't filter it by a simple `where` clause and must do first a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on Table B to match the needed Data and then I can use the `WHERE` clause. I've succeeded doing this in the Oracle SQL developer. But in the PHPMaker 2019, I'm currently unable to figure it out.

---

The Simplified samples:

Table A

| RECORD_IDENTITY | MyData1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Data1_AAA |
| 2 | Data1_BBB |
| 3 | Data1_CCC |
| 4 | Data1_AAA |
| 5 | Data1_BBB |
| 6 | Data1_CCC |
| 7 | Data1_AAA |
| 8 | Data1_BBB |
| 9 | Data1_CCC |

Table B

| RECORD_IDENTITY | MyData1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Data1_AAA |
| 2 | Data1_BBB |
| 3 | Data1_CCC |
| 4 | Data1_DDD |
| 5 | Data1_EEE |
| 6 | Data1_FFF |
| 7 | Data1_GGG |
| 8 | Data1_HHH |
| 9 | Data1_III |

(The sample data written here is not logical - just a sample)

---

I've simplified the sample tables to the core situation.

**I need** to show only the `DISTINCT MyData1` from Table A with the highest `RECORD_IDENTITY` each. Like this:

Table A

| RECORD_IDENTITY | MyData1 |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | Data1_AAA |
| 8 | Data1_BBB |
| 9 | Data1_CCC |

In Oracle SQL Developer my statement is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  T1.record_identity,
  T1.MyData1
FROM  Table A T1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Table B T2
    ON T2.MyData1 = T1.MyData1 AND T2.record_identity > T1.record_identity
WHERE (T2.record_identity IS NULL)
order by record_identity ASC;
```

This gives me exactly what I need.

My Problem is: How to do this in PHPMaker 2019?

I'm pretty new to this tool and haven't figured out every aspect of this. But I know that's possible to filter data in the "Table-Specific > Recordset_Selecting" area. My recent approaches always ended in errors :-( Google-Search is not very helpful for me here.

Maybe I've overseen a simpler way to do this in the sql statement.

Comment: Okay. I've got one improvement about the SQL Statement:

`
with table_max as(
select
max(record_identity) record_identity,
MyData1
from Table A
group by MyData1
)
select *
FROM  Table A T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table_max T2
       ON T2.record_identity = T1.record_identity
WHERE T2.MyData1= T1.MyData1
order by T1.record_identity ASC;
`

This makes an join of other tables obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. After countless hours of trying, crying and despair the answer is: No, you can't do this.

If you need to have special filtering like the mentioned or even need informations from other tables, then you need to create an custom view. There you can place your desired sql statement.

After this view has been created, you can assign the primary key and make all the settings as known from tables. The data can be edited in the web-view and will be written in the corresponding table(s).

//Edit: If you want to update only one Table, you have select the created view in the navigation, then to go to the "Code" tab and there you can see "Table-Specific".

There you have to insert `$this->UpdateTable = "YourBaseTable";` in "Page_Load" of each page type, which will be capable of editing data. In my situation: "Edit Page" and "List Page"